# Python: Gradient of matrix function

Tags: python, numpy, gradient

I want to calculate the gradient of the following function h(x) = 0.5 x.T * A * x + b.T + x.

For now I set A to be just a (2,2) Matrix.

```
def function(x):
    return 0.5 * np.dot(np.dot(np.transpose(x), A), x) + np.dot(np.transpose(b), x)
```

where

```
A = A = np.zeros((2, 2))
n = A.shape[0]
A[range(n), range(n)] = 1
```

a (2,2) Matrix with main diagonal of 1 and

```
b = np.ones(2)
```

For a given Point x = (1,1) numpy.gradient returns an empty list.

```
x = np.ones(2)  
result = np.gradient(function(x))
```

However shouldn't I get something like that: grad(f((1,1)) = (x1 + 1, x2 + 1) = (2, 2).

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to perform symbolic differentiation or automatic differentiation which `np.gradient` does not do. `sympy` is a package for symbolic math and `autograd` is a package for automatic differentiation for numpy. For example, to do this with `autograd`:

```
import autograd.numpy as np
from autograd import grad

def function(x):
    return 0.5 * np.dot(np.dot(np.transpose(x), A), x) + np.dot(np.transpose(b), x)

A = A = np.zeros((2, 2))
n = A.shape[0]
A[range(n), range(n)] = 1
b = np.ones(2)
x = np.ones(2)
grad(function)(x)
```

Outputs:

```
array([2., 2.])
```